# Xcode 4.5 armv6 error when not having armv6 in target?

Tags: ios, xcode, armv6

Hello,

I am currently getting the follow errors. I have tried everything posted before in other forums.
This is Xcode 4.5
I know it doesn't really support armv6,
I have tried manually adding it and it still comes up.

I have tried switching over the Build Active Architecture Only to NO, and get over 100 errors regarding armv6.

I feel like I have tried everything people have been posting and nothing seems to clean up the problem!

Comment: You haven't actually posted any errors. We'll need that to begin to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the "Valid architectures" for any traces of armv6 as well as "Architectures" in your build settings for both your project and your target.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to check that the minimum supported iOS version you are targeting is at least iOS 4.3.